# Setting consistent rowHeight in AgGrid-React

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using the `ag-grid-community:^24.1.0` and `ag-grid-react: ^24.1.1`in the react application. When I set the rowHeight as 25, it is displayed as shown below.

```
<div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={ { height: 400, width: 600 } }>
            <AgGridReact rowSelection="multiple"
                rowData={rowData}
                rowHeight={25}>
                ...
            </AgGridReact>
        </div>
```

[image]

I tried setting
`div.ag-theme-alpine div.ag-cell{font-size: 12px !important;vertical-align: middle;}` as told in some other posts but there is no change.
However, when I remove the following property from the developer tool, it starts appearing fine.

[image]

I want to set the uniform rowHeight(other than the default). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the row height to be static in the `gridOptions` or via the property `rowHeight={25}` the way you did.
However, agGrid also has a hardcoded value for the line-height that makes the rows only accept single line text.
changing the `lineHeight`, to something you prefer is the way to go if you want to start changing the `rowHeight` in addition to the fixed value.

Note: `rowHeight` field values don't work at all if you are in the `infiniteRow` model that is commonly used for server-side pagination because agGrid has problems calculating `rowHeights` and `gridHeights` if it doesn't know the full extent of the rows data.

if you want to change the lineHeight on all cells you can use the defaultColDef attribute `cellClass` and pass a class that forces the `lineHeight`

**EDIT:** here is how I do it,
in the defaultColDef object :

```js
defaultColDef: {
      ....
      cellClass:'cell-wrap-text',
      ....
}
```

then define that class like this:

```css
.cell-wrap-text{
  white-space: normal !important;
  line-height: 23px !important;
}
```

the whitespace line will make your text break and go back to line, since agGrid doesn't allow that by default.

after doing so, you can set the `rowHeight` in the react component like you already did.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Do you perhaps have any example